# Making Google Chrome my default browser disables hyper-links in Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, windows-live-messenger

Making Google Chrome my default browser disables hyper-links in Windows Live Messenger?  They show up just as text. How can I fix this, besides making Firefox default again?